# Get pixel coordinates for a given line

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, coordinates, line

Suppose you have two points **A(12,34)** and **B(56,78)** and you draw a straight line between them. I would like to get all pixels (their coordinates) for my given line. Is there a simple algorithm on that ?

I cant seem to use opencv's LineIterator. Its just not there. I think they did not implement the function in opencv2.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Bresenham's Line Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).